# how to install git+node+npm in /home/user?

Tags: node.js, continuous-integration, installation

I would like to have a self-installation script that i could use to have several installations of git + node.js + npm, all working in isolation in userland (with requiring root access).

One of the goal is to have a continuous integration setup that would

- isolate installation of several branches/tags
- recompile the bundle from source everytime

I suspect that such a script already exists somewhere but could not find one.

Is there a best-practice somewhere that I am missing ?

Thank you for your help

Comment: This isn't an exact answer to your question, but it may help: https://gist.github.com/1449558

Answer (score 0):

i don't understand why you'd want to have isolated copies of git, but for node and npm check out [this blog post](http://increaseyourgeek.wordpress.com/2010/08/18/install-node-js-without-using-sudo/).